# Exporting region of orthomosaic using QGIS to TIFF lacks TFW file

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

I have a very large orthomosaic that's come via Pix4d, which I'm trying to move into AutoCAD. Because its so large I understand that Pix4d use their own proprietary .TIF format which AutoCAD can't read. QGIS is happy with it so I've been dragging it over to QGIS and then exporting regions.

Recently when I've tried to export a region it doesn't save a separate .TFW file. Just the TIFF. How do I force this?

Comment: ok so its working for jpegs just not tiff. That will have to do for now

Answer (score 5):

Under the `Save as` raster window, there is a section called `Create options`, click the plus `+` button. Under `Name` column, write `tfw`, and under `Value` column write `yes`. It will export the raster as tif file format, and it will add a `tfw` file as well in your hard drive.